# Does an infinite solenoid have constant magnetic field along its length?

Tags: magnetic-fields, inductance

So I'm aware of the fact that an infinitely long solenoid has radially uniform(constant) magnetic field inside. But does the magnetic field vary as one moves along its length?

Reading the [solenoid article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid) on Wikipedia it says:

> Note, though, that nothing prohibits it from varying longitudinally,
>   which in fact it does.

However in his answer to this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14024/why-is-the-magnetic-field-inside-a-solenoid-constant), user Ted Bunn states that the field does not change along its length, and the reason behind this- he argues -is that the solenoid is translation-invariant along the axis so that no point along its length is different than the other.

So does it vary along its length or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnetic field should *not* change along its length because of the fact that it is infinite.  No one point along its length can be considered different from any other point since it is no closer to either end in the infinite solenoid case.

What the wikipedia article is talking about varying longitudinally is the integrand of Ampere's law when choosing an amperian loop that is larger longitudinally.

In this case you have:

$\oint \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l}=\mu_0 I_{\text{enc}}$

If you choose an amperian loop (that is square like is usually done for this case) that is longer in the radial direction, there is no change to this equation because $\vec{B}$ is along a part of the loop that did not change length and you are not enclosing anymore current.  If you extend the loop longitudinally, you are enclosing more current in the loop, but also you are increasing the length of the path along $d\vec{l}$ such that it cancels out the effect on enclosing more current, and the result is that $\vec{B}$ is the same no matter what loop size you choose.